# TypeError: $(...).gridstack is not a function #709

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gridstack

This is my sequence of scripts:

```
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"
src="../dist/gridstack.js"
src="gridstack.js"
src="../dist/gridstack.min.js"
href="../dist/gridstack.css"
href="../dist/gridstack.min.css"
```

This is my JavaScript code in which I used the gridstack function but it is showing errors. Please check the sequence of scripts and JavaScript file.

```
    $(function () {
 alert("1");
    $('.grid-stack').gridstack({
        animate: true,
        auto: true,
        width: 12,
        float: true,
        vertical_margin: 0,
        always_show_resize_handle: /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
        resizable: {
            handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w'
        }   
    });

    $('.grid-stack-placeholder').remove();

    this.grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

    this.add_widget = function(){
     alert("OK");

        var id = getRandomInt(1111,9999);

        var el = $.parseHTML("<div><div class=\"grid-stack-item-content\" data-id=\""+id+"\"/><div/>");
        this.grid.add_widget(el, 0, 0, 6, 5, true);

        $('.grid-stack-item-content[data-id="'+id+'"]').append('<span class="fa fa-times remove-widget"> </span><span class="fa fa-pencil select-use"></span>  </span><span class="fa fa-plus add-nested-widget-box"></span> ');

    }.bind(this);

    this.clear_grid = function () {
        this.grid.remove_all();
    }.bind(this);

    $('.clear-customization, .customize-pages-list li').click(this.clear_grid); 
    $('.add-widget-box').click(this.add_widget);

});

$('body').on('click', '.remove-widget', function(){

    var grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

    grid.remove_widget($(this).parents().eq(1));

});


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: yeah a bit more code would help

Comment: use jquery.min.js on the top of sequence

Comment: Used on the top but same issue.

Comment: how many time will you add gridstack mann  either remove the min file or the production file

Comment: @RAHULSR now check the qus

Comment: @Tech whats the change??

Comment: @RAHULSR I added the javascript file

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

put the css on top instead of with js files

```
 href="../dist/gridstack.css"
```

on the end

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"
src="../dist/gridstack.js"
```

remove those gridstack.min.js from your js since you are using the dev version of it

even if that not works then try this

```
<script>
$.noConflict();


  $('.grid-stack').gridstack({
        animate: true,
        auto: true,
        width: 12,
        float: true,
        vertical_margin: 0,
        always_show_resize_handle: /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
        resizable: {
            handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w'
        }   
    });
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).gridstack is not a function
 

$('.grid-stack').gridstack({

 demo.js (line 3, col 1)

Comment: gridstack is classing with any of the js file i advice you to reemove all js file except jquery and grid tsack then run it again if that works try adding js files one by one and try to know which js is causing the trouble